# Most "English-Like" solution to Project Euler # 1

Tags: haskell

Beginner Haskell learner here. I've solved Project Euler Problem 1, sum of multiples of 3 or 5 less than 1000, but I'm looking for a "more English-like" functional representation.

I created a function called multiples

```
multiples::(Integral a) => a -> [a]
multiples a = map (*a) [1..]
```

which I'm happy with, but I wish I could say

```
multiples of::(Integral a) => a -> [a]
multiples of a = map (*a) [1..]
```

to read more like English, but I get a parse error on input `of'

I want my functional declarations to read something like:

```
sum of multiples of::(Type)=>Type->Type
```

Any hope?

Comment: Why do you want this anyway? Haskell allows you to write in quite a variety of styles, but its type system is a bit too rigid to allow for a syntax as ambiguous as spoken languages are. That's probably more of a task for languages like Perl, or in fact for languages specialized on [word sense induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_sense_induction). (I don't actually know any, would be quite interesting though.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's kind of silly, but you can just define "words", and ignore the arguments in your "English" function:

```
by = ()
multiply a _ b = a*b

multiply 10 by 12
--120
```

However in your example you're out of luck, as `of` is a keyword (used in `case of`).

By the way, here is another way of defining multiples:

```
multiples_of = scanl1 (+) . repeat

take 10 $ multiples_of 12
--[12,24,36,48,60,72,84,96,108,120]
```

Comment: Does Haskell support defining ` of` as operator (with backquotes)? I just noticed with some surprise that Frege allows this.

Comment: @Ingo: yes, Haskell allows definition and usage of (binary) functions in this manner. e.g. `x \`of\` y = ...` or `(*n) \`map\` [1..]`

Comment: Also, dude, underscores are not the preferred nomenclature.  [camelCase](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Camel_case), please :)

Comment: @Porges - Sure, I know this, but does it also work with keywords?

Comment: @Ingo: Ah, I see the problem :) It appears not.